# phpMyAdmin MySQL password reset does not let me login

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Hey and thanks for reading, i am locked out of my own server...

I went to `http://localhost/security/` and changed the mysql password for the root user , apparently was not such a good idea because i cant access my phpmyadmin site anymore to configure mysql, WHY?

I've looked online but all they talk about is how to reset your password, I would like to know how I can login into the current phpmyadmin now after i changed the mysql password .

Please help this vulnerable noob be less vulnerable

Bonus: Is there a way to protect the sites on local host with a password

Comment: answer is : so i found why iam not able to atenticate with the new credentials in phpmyadmin and that is because in the file config.inc.php the line  `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']            = 'http'; /* Authentication method (config, http or cookie based) */` on default is set to cookie, i changed it to http and now it asks me for a login

Answer (score 7):

find the `config.inc.php` file in your phpmyadmin folder and you'll be able to enter the password to use.

Comment: the problem that i have is that when i edit or change the password i dont get a login

Comment: that didn't work for me. I tried password with AllowNoPassword = false, and no password with AllowNoPassword = true. Restarted mysql each time. Still can't login

Answer (score 1):

are you using windows ???

if yes

- I tried to login after edit password in `config.inc.php` as @abhinav say  but

  with no result :(

but i think you can login using this way

in localhost  password is saved in database called **mysql**

and the user table is **users**

if i were you

if i have script in my localhost

i will try to edit php files and make sql injection hole  or sql query

to get the password from mysql.users and crack it   or edit it

other way is

database is stored in files in this path  like me

`c:/appserv/mysql/data/mysql/users.myd`

my localhost password is 1 and this is my file

[My users.myd file and mypassword is 1](http://www.rwabt.com/attach/fd50217786.zip)

Try To Replace This File With Your File :)

BestRegards

Comment: nice idea , was looking for a legit solution but i gave a try to what you wrote and it appears that the passwords are hashed with i think md5 so if i want to change the password i just generate the password i want with md5 and replace the one in that file and it works !!!!

Comment: But come on !!!!!! why is there not a straight forward method for this

Comment: mysql password is not **md5**   if you want to encode password take this `606717496665bcba` its from my mysql.user pass , yes its not safe solution but you can try it and don't forget to take backup from `users.myd` file

Answer (score -1):

I changed the password of root user in `phpmyadmin` (xampp) and then I could not enter to phpmyadmin. The #1045 error did not appear but the page to enter the password was reloaded again. But when I connected to the database by using a sql manager (`heidiSQL`), I could enter using root user and password I changed.

I tried to change the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']` to `http`, but it didn't work. Then I tried to enter to phpmyadmin using `127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin` and I could enter using the password I changed.